Removing an lvm2 pv partition after failed OS installation
I recently attempted to manually partition my drive in order to install a second operating system. I currently use Nobara and was attempting to install VanillaOS as a secondary OS. I am trying to uninstall VanillaOS and am able to delete 3 of the 4 partitions, but one of them shows the lock as if it is mounted in KDE. The partition is /dev/nvme0n1p8 and the file system is lvm2 pv. The mount point says vos-root. I found this question How to deactivate a LVM2 physical volume to remove the drive? but after following both solutions I keep receiving the errors "Volume group "nvme0n1p8" not found" and "Cannot process volume group nvme0n1p8." How can I delete/re-format this partition?

WHat is the result of commands: vgs, lvs and pvs?
